# Internet Information Service(IIS) Manager issue

Tags: c#, iis

I am publishing my site in IIS and my WebDav folder is configured in other PC of IIS.

I want to get that website name using some c# code.

How can I get the `site name` of my WebDav folder in my published web site (ex: `Default Web Site`) using c# code?

Comment: Do you know on which socket is your website? Type the ip of the host machine of your website and the socket for the http and check how it gets resolved in the browse.

Comment: You can use IP address for IP and physical path of other machine folder should be authorized to access required information over network. then you can see your application in browser.

Comment: i want to get the site name using C# code....how is it possible...??

Comment: I have IP address of my WebDav folder....but how can i get site name of it using c# code..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to figure out what Site Name(s) exist on an IIS instance from the IP address?

take a look at this artice:
http://cstruter.com/blog/306

and where you see this line of code:

```
foreach (Website site in GetSites("IIS://localhost/W3SVC"))
```

put the IP address where you see localhost. if the ip address was 123.123.123.123 then it would look like this:

```
foreach (Website site in GetSites("IIS://123.123.123.123/W3SVC"))
```

You will need adequate permissions to enumerate the Sites! (see the comments below the article for some notes on this)

Comment: thank you @montewhizdoh for help me...
but still i had error like..

http://i.imgur.com/f30dAbS.png